# How can I find the sum of squares of binomial coefficient and fibonacci numbers $ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left[ \binom{n}{k}F_k \right]^2 $

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, fibonacci-numbers

In this topic ([Binomial coefficient and fibonacci numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227687/binomial-coefficient-and-fibonacci-numbers)), it can be easily seen the sum of binomial coefficient and fibonacci numbers is

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}F_k = F_{2n}.
$$

I have also proved it via Binet formula of the Fibonacci numbers ( you can find the Binet formula in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html).

Hereby, how can I find the following sum of the square of this summation formula

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \left[ \binom{n}{k}F_k \right]^2 = ?
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Again using Binet's formula with $\phi:=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\,\varphi:=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$, the left-hand side is $$\frac{1}{5}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^2(\phi^{2k}+\varphi^{2k}-2(-1)^k).$$In terms of Legendre functions of the first kind, [according to Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20((n%20choose%20k)%5E2*x%5Ek)%20from%200%20to%20n) $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}^2x^k=(1-x)^nP_n\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right).$$The desired result simplifies to $$\frac{1}{5}\left((-\phi)^nP_n\left(-\sqrt{5}\right)+\phi^{-n}P_n\left(\sqrt{5}\right)-2^{n+1}P_n\left(0\right)\right).$$

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. Can we represent your result with Fibonacci numbers?